# I have lost the ability to edit posts on stackoverflow. Why is this?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)
>   [I'm no longer able to edit questions — Is there anything I can do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102386/im-no-longer-able-to-edit-questions-is-there-anything-i-can-do)

For the last couple of days every question that I view does not have the edit link available to me.

I have the `link | flag` options available but I cannot edit questions.

Why would this be? Is there a limit on questions I can edit? It has been over two days now.

I am logged in.

Comment: In your case the problem seems to be that you make minor retags without full edit rights, and people think it's not worth the reviewing effort for such minor edits.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337 for the criteria used.  The linked post confirms that this ban will likely be lifted in 7 days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to your edit stats, more than 50% of your suggested edits were rejected.

Editing rights can get removed after at certain rejection thresholds. I believe you have hit one of these thresholds.

Comment: How do I resolve this? Will I ever get my editing rights back??

Comment: I can only suggest one thing: be patient. I don't know the authoritative answer, but you've only waited two days which seems a tad short. If you don't get those rights back in a couple weeks, you might try emailing the team. But make sure you contribute good content in the meantime - that will play in your favor should you have to escalate this issue.

Answer (score 7):

[This might have something to do with it...](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/130546)

[image: Image showing the editor stats, 30 approved, 34 rejected.]